# Python loop importing, Error with no attribute

Tags: python

This is the code in question.

```
for files in os.listdir('./apps'):
    if files.endswith(".py"):
        imported = importlib.import_module(files[:-3])
i=tk.Button(root,text=imported.MainWindow.buttonname,command=imported.MainWindow)
```

In this code I am looping through a directory called apps, for every .py file in this directory I need to import it and a class called mainWindow (every .py file has a mainWindow class), I get this error though.

```
module 'test' has no attribute 'mainWindow'
```

```
class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Toplevel
        self.window.geometry('500x500')
```

here is my mainWindow class in test.py

Update
i tried

```
importedmainclass = importlib.import_module(imported.MainWindow)
```

Still got the error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked and confirmed that `test.py` has `mainWindow`?

Comment: I put it in the post that it does, but updated to make i clearer.

Comment: Can you show how the file test.py is done?

Comment: If you can share `test.py`, it would be possible for us to try and recreate this error

Comment: Yup edited with the test.py code

Comment: mainWindow or MainWindow ?? I think you only have to change the lower m

Comment: I fixed it in my code to be MainWindow because i thought that could be the issue but the error still happens.

Answer (score 1):

Your test.py uses `MainWindow`, while the code uses `.mainWindow` at the second to last line. Fix that, and it should work, or at least throw a different error :-).

Comment: Ah i fixed this in my code but still throws the same error that it has no attribute MainWindow

Comment: ```MainWindow``` or ```mainWindow``` ? 
Did you remove both inputs ?

Comment: i changed it so it all uses MainWindow

Comment: Could you please edit the question and provide a) current code b) current error message? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```
importedmainclass = getattr(importlib.import_module(imported.__name__), 'MainWindow')
```

And add in the directory ./apps a file `__init__.py` for example this is like:

```
def __init__():
    pass
```

Comment: Hello i tried the first thing you suggested and i still get the same error,

For the second thing i don't think i understand why/how i am supposed to do this, if you could elaborate that would be helpful. < disregard this upon further research i have found the reason

Moving on the issue still persists